# Codeigniter - if else inside view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am designing a theme layout for my web app.

Let's say if I have two controllers,A and B. I want A view to display div A and B view will display div B.

I know how to set this inside the controller by utilizing `if($this->router->fetch_class() == 'A')
{
  //display div A
}`

But, how to achieve this in view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noooo.  Don't do it that way. ;)  Hard-coding strings for this sort of thing is almost always a bad approach.  Your views will get messy, and good luck ever renaming your controller classes.

First, if this code is in your controller, *don't you know which controller it is?*

This makes me assume that this is an inherited method that is used by multiple controllers, right?  In which case, there are a few options:

1. **Override it on a per-child basis**, telling the `parent::some_action()` method which div you want to display.  (Proper delegation of "authority" here will save you some decoupling headaches later on...)
2. Rather than using `fetch_class()`, **use `instanceof`** (so that your IDE will do the heavy lifting for you if you ever rename the class).
3. Consider **splitting this stuff into subviews** (i.e. partials).  It gets *really* messy to do string comparisons in a view.  Trust. Me.

Here's what I would recommend:

```
<?php
// Overridden core class
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function some_action()
    {
        //...
        if ($this instanceof Controller_class_that_uses_div_a)
        {
            $this->load->view('view_for_div_A');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('view_for_div_B');
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was baffled at the question myself. I agree here. You don't want to get in the habit of doing controller things in views. For the sake of anyone else alive that will have to mess with this code, please keep it simple and contained.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the same logic in your controller and just pass the value down to your view:

```
$class = $this->router->fetch_class();

$this->load->view('myView', 
                  array('class' => $class));
```

Then just use that variable in your view:

```
if ($class == 'A') ...
```

Comment: Ouch, Just because it is not some regular string, I thought it can't be passed to the view like that..Thanks.will give it a try

Comment: Yes, there are no restrictions that I am aware of; other types of objects can be passed to a view besides just strings.